# How to compare 2 array of PHP objects then fill in empty string if data not match?

Tags: php, arrays, object, compare

There has 2 array with different size, the array need to filled in with empth string if data not match.

Array A with 3 objects inside:

```
$array_A = [
             {"code":"1","cost":30},
             {"code":"3","cost":100},
             {"code":"4","cost":50}
          ]
```

Array B with 5 objects inside:

```
$array_B = [
             {"code":"1"},
             {"code":"2"},
             {"code":"3"},
             {"code":"4"},
             {"code":"5"}
          ]
```

Then, I need to compare array A and array B with attribute `code`, if the `code` is same, the fill in the `cost` attribute, else let the `cost` == 0. 
As shown below :-

Array New:

```
$array_New = [
             {"code":"1","cost":30},
             {"code":"2","cost":0},
             {"code":"3","cost":100},
             {"code":"4","cost":50},
             {"code":"5","cost":0}
          ]
```

This is my solution (but cannot worked):

> > Compare array A and array B with two for-loops then fill the data into array_New

```
$array_New= array();

foreach ($array_B as $key => $array_B_data) {
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($array_A) ; $i++) { 
    if ($array_B_data->code == $array_A[$i]->code) {    

        $array_New[$key] = $array_A[$i]['cost'];
    }else{
        $array_New[$key] = '';

        }
    }

}

return $array_New;
```

However, the $array_New do not display the data as shown in Array New. 
Can anyone give me some guidance?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Why json values inside an array? Why not have a symmetric structure throughout?

Comment: Actually the data I was generated from the Laravel PHP model. The code above I just make it more understandable. This is the array with PHP objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this!

```
new_array= array();
foreach ($array_B as $key => $data) {
    $found = false;
    $cost = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($array_A);$i++){
        if($array_A[$i]['code']==$data['code']){
        $found = true;
        $cost = $array_A[$i]['cost'];
    }
}
// print_r($data);
if (!$found){
  $new_array[count($new_array)+1] = ['code'=>$data['code'], 'cost'=>$cost];
}else{
  $new_array[count($new_array)+1] = ['code'=>$data['code'], 'cost'=>$cost];
}
}
```

Comment: @Woshington Valdeci, thanks for your help. This is the correct answer for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Making use of an associative array will work way faster than 2 nested loops. Here is the code snippet below:

```
<?php

function make($code,$cost = null){
    $o = new stdclass();
    $o->code = $code;
    if(!is_null($cost)) $o->cost = $cost;
    return $o;
}

$array_A = [
            make("1",30),
            make("3",100),
            make("4",50),
          ];

$array_B = [
            make("1"),
            make("2"),
            make("3"),
            make("4"),
            make("5")
          ];

$set = [];


foreach($array_A as $current){
    if(!property_exists($current,'cost')) $current->cost = 0;
    if(!isset($set[$current->code]) || $set[$current->code]->cost == 0 && $current->cost > 0) $set[$current->code] = $current;
}

foreach($array_B as $current){
    if(!property_exists($current,'cost')) $current->cost = 0;
    if(!isset($set[$current->code]) || $set[$current->code]->cost == 0 && $current->cost > 0) $set[$current->code] = $current;
}


print_r(array_values($set));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/9IWcp

- We make us of an array `$set` where it's key is the `code` and value is the object itself as `{code:xyz,cost:xyz}`.
- We move across elements of both arrays and if an element does not have a `cost` property, we explicitly assign `cost` as `0` and insert that in our `$set`.
- In case, `$set` already that code as a key, we compare both `$current`'s cost and the stored one's cost and insert the non-zero cost value object(if present) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your patiently explanation ! Appreciate it !